# I cannot get rid of these extra sheets in excel vba. only the sheets with a name exist

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot get rid of these extra sheets in excel vba. only the sheets with a name exist.

[image]

Comment: *How* are you trying to "get rid" of these sheets? Please add that code to your post.

Comment: Is this link similar?  https://superuser.com/questions/1005482/excel-creates-non-existent-worksheets-in-vba-project-explorer

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I used the option Book Inspection in the Information Menu, then I selected remove hidden objects and it luckily worked. See the image attached, my excel is in Spanish so maybe the option is not really called "Book inspection" in the English version.

Hope this is useful.

Pd- Unhide the legitimate sheets because it will delete all hidden sheets. I suggest trying it in a copy of the book. [Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc0qU.png) [Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63FOs.png)